# getDynamicLink(intent) function is not completing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm currently working on a kotlin project that uses Firebase. Here (among other things) I let users create campaigns that are registered with a uid on firestore and let the creators send dynamic links to others to join them.
Once clicked the link should redirect to a specific activity and allow the joiner to make some (irrelevant) actions to then register the id of the new member in the campagn memberlist (stored in said campaign file on firestore).

The problem I'm encountering is that the getDynamicLink(intent) function seems to not return anything. The onSuccessListener and the onFailureListener are never entered and if I try to print out the task it says that said task is not completed. I can't seem to place an onCompletion listener wither.

I checked the Firebase documentation but there it simply says to call the function and for a bit that worked as intended, correctly registering the members, but after tweaking other functions it stopped working and I seem to be unable to understand why.
The intent filter correctly works, since the correct activity is opened, but the function's listener is never entered.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_join_campaign)
        
        Log.e("debug", "out of function") //this is shown

        //intercettazione del link con intent
        Firebase.dynamicLinks.getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData : PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
                Log.e("debug", "in function") //this is never shown

                // Get the deep link from the Dynamic Link data
                var deepLink : Uri? = null
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData?.link == null){
                    return@addOnSuccessListener
                }
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "link $deepLink") //this is never shown
                
                //other code 
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "error handling link")
            }
}
```

(first post here so let me know if I need to show something else or made some mistakes, thank you)

As mentioned, I expect it to at least show the "in function" log but it never shows. Furthermore if I try to print the intent by logging it before calling the function it's printed (i think) correctly:
`Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://gestorednd1.page.link/joinjoinjoin99 flg=0x13000000 cmp=com.example.gestorednd/.Activities.JoinCampaignActivity }`

I've triple checked the intent filters in my file and in my manifest (which I don't think are the problem since the correct activity shows up).